# Is $\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{inx}dx=0$ for $n \neq 0$?

Tags: definite-integrals

How can we prove this using Cauchy's Integral? We know that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx} dx = 0$ for $n$ not equal to $0$, and is equal to $2\pi$ for $n=0$, how can we prove that $\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{inx} dx=0$ for $n \neq 0$

Comment: You can't prove it, because [it's not true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+from+0+to+pi%2F2+of+exp%28ix%29).

Comment: It can 0 for some values of n. But it is not general.

Comment: @CameronWilliams indeed, mea culpa

Comment: You know it doesn't take anything more than calculus to actually _evaluate_ that integral...

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{inx} dx= [\frac{1}{in}e^{inx}]_0^{\pi/2}.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The integral is$$\left[\frac{1}{in}e^{inx}\right]_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{e^{in\pi/2}-1}{in}=\frac2n\sin\frac{n\pi}{4}e^{in\pi/4}.$$This is nonzero if $4\nmid n$.